# Django model instance reference not saving Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models:

```
class Business(models.Model):
     ... #some fields

class Order(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
```

In one of my views, I'm trying to save a business to order as follows:

```
def view_name(request):
    business_id = request.DATA['business'] #using Django Rest
    business = Business.objects.get(id=business_id)
    order = Order(business=business)
    order.save()
    return Response('some response')
```

The view throws no errors but when I open the order in Django Admin or in the DB Admin view, it shows NO linked business. Why is that? Where have I gone wrong

EDIT: Okay so, I've dropped and recreated DB and I can now see the `business_id` in my PostGresAdmin but I don't see it in my Django admin panel. Attached screenshots:

Screenshots

My Admin:

[image: Admin Panel not showing associated business]

My PG Admin tool:

[image: PGAdmin showing business]

Comment: did you per chance disable `autocommit`? otherwise there is no reason for it not to save immediately. For debug, wrap the Order creation in a `try/except` and see if anything is triggered that is not bubbling up

Comment: @Incognos, Added edits to the OP.

Comment: Ok, you need to do some homework: are you sure that `business = Business.objects.get(id=business_id)` is returning a valid record? are you sure that `business_id = request.DATA['business']` is bringing a good value ? btw, you should change that to `request.DATA.get('business')`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def view_name(request):
    business_id = request.DATA['business'] #using Django Rest
    business = Business.objects.get(id=business_id)
    order = Order.objects.create(business=business)
    order.save()
    return Response('some response')
```

Comment: This works (even without the additional save). But it does not really explain why OP's version doesn't.

Comment: `save` is not necessary when you `create`.

Comment: Added screenshots and edited my question. Hopefully it throws light on the errors.

Answer (score 0):

simply:

```
business = Business.objects.get(id=business_id)
order = business.order_set.create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what data is being returned, you may not be getting the data you expect.

```
def view_name(request):
    business_id = request.DATA.get('business', None) #using Django Rest
    if business_id:
        business = Business.objects.get(id=business_id)
        except Business.Multiple
        order = Order(business=business)
        order.save()
        return Response('some response')
     return Response("Could not create Order")
```